# I want to create a zipped output file while keeping the original one

Tags: shell-script

I want to create a zipped output file while keeping the original one. I want to do it from Informatica end by using command task or session task.

Below is the example which I am trying:

1. In session task: Command type='Command',
                   Command=
      `gzip -c /var/opt/powermart/pc8_dev/infa_shared/TgtFiles/test1/tgt_zip.out`
2. In case of using Command task:

   `gzip -c /var/opt/powermart/pc8_dev/infa_shared/TgtFiles/test1/tgt_zip.out`

I tried both things, but zip file is not at all created.

Below is the screen shot:

[image: command in session task]

Answer (score 4):

You can keep original file by using `-c` options and redirect output to another file:

```
gzip -c file > file.gz
```

It will keep your original `file` unchange and create its gzip file named `file.gz`

Answer (score 0):

Your zip file isn't being created because the `-c` option for gzip means that the compressed file is sent to stdout instead of being written to disk. For what you want, you could either do what Laurent suggested in his comment, or you could use `zip` instead of `gzip`, which leaves the original files as well as creating a .zip file:

```
zip /var/opt/powermart/pc8_dev/infa_shared/TgtFiles/test1/tgt_zip.out.zip /var/opt/powermart/pc8_dev/infa_shared/TgtFiles/test1/tgt_zip.out
```

Or:

```
cd /var/opt/powermart/pc8_dev/infa_shared/TgtFiles/test1/ && zip tgt_zip tgt_zip
```

Answer (score 0):

`gzip -c` reads a file (or standard input when file name is - ) and writes a compressed version to standard output.

So save contents to a new file then stdout redirection can be used.

```
gzip -c inputfile >outputfile
```

To simply compress in place and produce inputfile.gz

```
gzip inputfile
```

If informatica is ignoring the `stdout` redirection, you could pass the whole command to a shell (sh, csh, bash, ...) and let it do it instead,

```
Command=sh -c "gzip -c filename > newfilename"
```

I'm not an informatica user, so their forum for more information on that product [here](https://community.informatica.com/message/41523#41523).

edit 1

Here's a simple script to use from informatica which hides i/o redirection.

```
$ cat infagzip.sh 
#!/bin/sh

if [ $# -ne 2 ]
then
    echo "Usage $0 : inputfile outputfile "
    exit 1
fi
 gzip -c "$1" > "$2"
```

Now your Command line should look like this

```
/path/to/infagzip.sh inputfilename outputfilename
```

Comment: I tried above logic but end up with below error:  Error: [tgt_zip] Process id 17626. The shell command failed with exit code 1.

Comment: Your problem appears to be the informatica interface,  write a simple shell command that just takes the parameters you require which can hide redirection and punctuation characters to informatica if this is causing the problem. BTW, you didn't try the sh method above.

Comment: @X Tian, if I ran first command in putty, it is giving expected result, but not in Inforamatica. I tried sh method also. its not working at Infa level.

Comment: Write a simple shell script to do what you want. and call that instead of gzip directly.